# Precisely how is the exit condition in a for loop computed?

Tags: c#, for-loop, exit, break

**NOTE**: see edit below before you read this.

I have a function that takes in a string and outputs an enum of a specified type if that string matches any members of that enum. I.e., I have some enum `SupportedFunctions` with members `CVT`, `VIS`, etc, and the function will return `SupportedFunctions.CVT` when passed `"CVT"`.

I have the following two functions:

`parse_enum`:

```
private bool parse_enum<EnumType>(string input, out EnumType out_enum)
{
    EnumType current_enum = (EnumType)(object)0;
    bool seeking = current_enum.ToString() != "0";
    for (int i = 0; seeking; i++)//THIS LINE
    {
        current_enum = (EnumType)(object)i;
        Console.WriteLine(current_enum);
        seeking = current_enum.ToString() != i.ToString();
        if (current_enum.ToString().ToLower() == input)
        {
            out_enum = current_enum;
            return true;
        }
}
```

and `parse_enum_2`:

```
private bool parse_enum_2<EnumType>(string input, out EnumType out_enum)
{
    EnumType current_enum = (EnumType)(object)0;
    for (int i = 0; current_enum.ToString() != i.ToString(); i++)//THIS LINE
    {
        current_enum = (EnumType)(object)i;
        Console.WriteLine(current_enum);
        if (current_enum.ToString().ToLower() == input)
        {
            out_enum = current_enum;
            return true;
        }
}
```

Note that both functions are exactly the save save for one thing: `parse_enum` computes the logical `seeking` and uses that for the loop exit condition, while `parse_enum_2` computes the equivalent expression for `seeking` in the for loop statement and uses that.

The `WriteLine` statement is temporary for debugging. The strange thing is that `parse_enum` works just fine, i.e. has output

```
VIS
CVT
CLR
3         <-----terminates since it has exhausted enum terms
```

while `parse_enum_2` has output

```
VIS
CVT
CLR
3
4
5
6
7
...
```

and never exits.

Why is this? I realize that there is an easier way to do this, but that is not the point here. I did a trick like this a while ago and compiled using CSC and it seemed to work. I am using Mono on Ubuntu at the moment, might that be making the difference?

**EDIT**: Thanks to those of you who have described how the condition works, but I do believe my question is more subtle than that. I will simplify the code: I have two functions:

Here is the first one, `func1`:

```
private static void func1()
{
    ConsoleColor current = (ConsoleColor)0;
    bool end = current.ToString() == 0.ToString();
    for (int i = 0; !end; i++)//HERE
    {
        current = (ConsoleColor)i;
        end = current.ToString() == i.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine("enum:" + current + ", i:" + i + ", condition:" + end);
        Console.ReadLine();//For stepping through
    }
}
```

and the second one, `func2`:

```
private static void func2()
{
    ConsoleColor current = (ConsoleColor)0;
    for (int i = 0; current.ToString() != i.ToString(); i++)//HERE
    {
        current = (ConsoleColor)i;

        Console.WriteLine("enum:" + current + ", i:" + i + ", condition:" + (current.ToString() != i.ToString()));
        Console.ReadLine();//For stepping through
    }
}
```

I have simplified the code so there isn't as much going on. I have printed `i`, the name of the current `enum` and the exit condition: the logical `end` in the first case, and the equivalent expression in the second case. This is the output I get:

For `func1`:

```
enum:Black, i=0, condition:True
enum:DarkBlue, i=1, condition:True
...
enum:White, i=15, condition:True
enum:16, i=16, condition:False //Program terminates
```

but for `func2`:

```
enum:Black, i=0, condition:True
enum:DarkBlue, i=1, condition:True
...
enum:White, i=15, condition:True
enum:16, i=16, condition:False
enum:17, i=17, condition:False
enum:18, i=18, condition:False
... //Program does not terminate
```

Perhaps I asked this the wrong way. However, it is very clear in the second case that `current.ToString() != i.ToString()` returns `false`, **yet the loop keeps going**. Again, I think this is actually a far more subtle issue than it appears. Perhaps I am missing something glaringly obvious?

Comment: I didn't read all your code, but to answer your question, the second expression in a for loop (the part between the two semi:colons) is evaluated right after the last statement in the associated block, and, if it's true, the loop loops back. If it's false, the code breaks out of the loop and execution continues after the code in the for loop's block

Comment: Actually,  reading it over, that's not true. The test is done at the start of the block (so that if it's false on the first pass, the block is never executed). That's paired with an unconditional jump from the end of the loop black to that test at the start of the block

Comment: Do you have to use this method? This is as roundabout a way as I've ever seen someone try to get done something super simple. You could just use `Enum.TryParse()` and get this done in two lines of codes.

Comment: @Sach I realize that that's easier. That's what my code looks like now but when I was experimenting I was getting unusual results. However, that isn't the point of the question.

Comment: The *current* variable always has the previous value of *i*, so the condition is never true.  Just move the Console.WriteLine call before the assignment of *current* and it will be obvious.

Answer (score 1):

The [language reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/for) states that the *condition* section executes before each loop iteration.

> The condition section, if present, must be a boolean expression. That expression is evaluated before every loop iteration. If the condition section is not present or the boolean expression evaluates to true, the next loop iteration is executed; otherwise, the loop is exited.

The *iterator* section happens after each loop iteration.

> The iterator section defines what happens after each iteration of the body of the loop.

Given your example, `i` will increment at the end of the loop, and then the new value of `i` will be compared to the value of `current_enum` before `current_enum` is assigned to the new value of `i`.

Comment: Thanks, but as far as I can tell, the issue is more subtle than this. Perhaps there was too much code to read through in my original post. I will make an edit.

Comment: It's in the last  sentence of the answer: `i` will increment at the end of the loop *before* the condition is evaluated, so in `func2` it will always be `true`.